# 405 Status Ngnix React

Tags: reactjs, nginx, react-router

I'm getting a 405 status code when making a POST request from my react app to my flask api. I've narrowed it down to Nginx as I'm able to curl the route successfully on the server.

From what I've researched, I'm getting the 405 status code because Nginx believes that it should be serving static content, but I do not understand why this is happening.

What makes it more confusing to me is that I am only getting the 405 status code on some endpoints but not others.

flask: Working Routes

```
@users_blueprint.route('/auth/login', methods=['POST'])
@users_blueprint.route('/classes/list', methods=['POST'])
@users_blueprint.route('/classes/add', methods=['POST'])
```

flask: Problem Routes

```
@users_blueprint.route('/auth/register', methods=['POST'])
@users_blueprint.route('/schedule/add', methods=['POST'])
@users_blueprint.route('/schedule/add', methods=['POST'])
```

React App.js

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
          <Switch>
              <Route exact path='/login' component={Login}/>
              <Route exact path='/register' component={Register}/>
              <PrivateRoute
                  path='/'
                  component={Main}
              />
          </Switch>
    );
  }
}
```

React Main.js

```
...
...
render() {
    const { classes, theme } = this.props;

    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <CssBaseline />
            <Nav mobileOpen={this.state.mobileOpen} handleDrawerToggle={this.handleDrawerToggle}/>
            <MenuBar menuText={this.state.menuTitle} handleDrawerToggle={this.handleDrawerToggle}/>
            <main className={classes.content}>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/clients/list' render={(props) => <ClientList {...props} setMenu={this.setMenu} />} />
                    <Route exact path='/clients/add' render={(props) => <ClientView {...props} setMenu={this.setMenu} />}/>
                    <Route exact path='/classes/add' render={(props) => <Classes {...props} setMenu={this.setMenu} />} />
                    <Route exact path='/classes/list' render={(props) => <ClassList {...props} setMenu={this.setMenu} />} />
                    <Route exact path='/schedule/list/:id' render={(props) => <ClassSchedule {...props} setMenu={this.setMenu} />} />
                    <Route exact path='/schedule/add/:id'render={(props) => <AddSchedule {...props} setMenu={this.setMenu} />} />
                    <Route exact path='/events/list/:id' render={(props) => <EventsList {...props} setMenu={this.setMenu} />} />
                </Switch>
            </main>
        </div>

    );
}
```

Ngnix default

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/fpt/build;
    server_name blahblah.compute-1.amazonaws.com;
    index index.html index.htm;
    location / {
          proxy_pass          http://localhost:5000/;
          proxy_set_header    Host             $host;
          proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header    X-Client-Verify  SUCCESS;
          proxy_set_header    X-Client-DN      $ssl_client_s_dn;
          proxy_set_header    X-SSL-Subject    $ssl_client_s_dn;
          proxy_set_header    X-SSL-Issuer     $ssl_client_i_dn;
    }
 }
```

I've tried many different patterns in the nginx config such as two server blocks listening on different ports and prefixing my endpoints with /api/ all with no luck. Any guidance is appreciated

edit: It is probably worth noting that the /schedule/ react routes are in subcomponents

log example:

```
xxx.xxx.x.xx - - [10/Jan/2019:03:46:59 +0000] "GET /register HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36"
xxx.xxx.x.xx - - [10/Jan/2019:03:47:00 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 3870 "blahblahblah.compute-1.amazonaws.com/register" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36"
xxx.xxx.x.xx - - [10/Jan/2019:03:47:04 +0000] "POST /auth/register HTTP/1.1" 405 584 "blahblha.compute-1.amazonaws.com/register" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: Did you verify the browser calls for the trouble methods are POST? The 405 makes me think the browser is sending the wrong verb. Also, anything in the nginx logs?

Comment: @KarlGalvez The browser shows that it is a post as well as the nginx logs. I updated the question with a few log entries